# Small, Custom WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I would make to make a small WYSIWYG editor similar to the one used by StackOverflow. Basically, it would have buttons like `[quote]`, and when that button is clicked, `[quote] [/quote]` should be inserted in the textarea where the cursor is or at the end of all other text. If the `[quote][/quote]` could be highlighted in some way that would be even more excellent, but its not required.

Is there any WYSIWYG editor already available where you can add custom buttons, with custom text being added to the textbox as a result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a good list of ten of the top ones on [this blog](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors).

Comment: Thanks, I used Jquery MarkItUp from that list, it allows custom buttons to be added with custom output. Very cool!

Answer (score 5):

Why not using [WMD Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/) (the one used by stackoverflow) and [configure](http://wmd-editor.com/features) its available buttons?

Answer (score 1):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) Works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use the one [stackoverflow does](http://wmd-editor.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for formatting.  Because Markdown is significantly simpler to generate and deal with than HTML, I'd imagine there are lots of good choices.  [This one](http://wmd-editor.com/examples/splitscreen) seems to match all the functionality of the one used by Stack Overflow, perhaps it's the same one!

If you're looking for something non-Markdown, then TinyMCE or CKEditor might be what you want.

Comment: Not sure Jeff is that big a fan - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/responsible-open-source-code-parenting.html

Comment: I have discovered that based on the other answers posted besides mine :)  It also looks awesome, and I think I will be integrating it into everything quite soon...

Answer (score -1):

You can use Microsoft Expression Web, it is free and comes in a bundle pack with other expression applications.  It has worked for me very well and I haven't had a problem with it.  Also [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) is a great source for Tutorials on code and such.